# Convert date in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, convert

I need a help to change the format of a date MM/dd /yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

I tried this:

Works!

```
Now: %%=Format(Now(),"MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
```

Does not work!

```
Date of Vestibular: %%=Format(%%Date Vestibular%%, "MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
```

Results:

```
Now: 15/07/2016 
Date Vestibular: %%=Format(7/27/2016 12:00:00 AM,"dd/MM/yyyy")=%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Personalization Strings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/) are referenced differently in functions and in AMPScript blocks.

Should be something like this:

```
Now: %%=Format(Now(),"MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
<br>Date of Vestibular: %%=Format([Date Vestibular], "dd/MM/yyyy")=%%
```

or better:

```
%%[

var @DateVestibular
set @DateVestibular = AttributeValue("Date Vestibular")

]%%

Now: %%=Format(Now(),"MM/dd/yyyy")=%%
<br>Date of Vestibular: %%=Format(@DateVestibular, "dd/MM/yyyy")=%%
```

Comment: Adam,  Thanks for your reply, I will take the test now,
"I forgot" to use [] :)

Comment: Works! Data do Vestibular: 27/07/2016 ! Tks

Comment: Adam, I saw that you know well the marketing cloud, I wonder if I have to perform queries directly on native tables, for example, _Sent, _Bounce?

Comment: The System Data Views have to be enabled by SFMC Support.  Once that's done, yes, you can.

Comment: Adam,

Please can you explain how I can ask for support?

Or simply open a case requesting access the System Data Views?

What is the best way to apply for this support?